# use iostream or alternative for managing stream

Tags: c++, iostream

I want to write a function which (simplified) takes as a parameter an input buffer of variable size, processes it (sequentially), and returns a buffer of a fixed size. The remaining part of the buffer has to stay in the "pipeline" for the next call of the function.

Question 1:
From my research it looks like iostream is the way to go, but apparently no one is using it. Is this the best way to go?

Question 2:
How can I declare the iostream object globally? Actually, as I have several streams I will need to write the iostream Object in a struct-vector. How do I do this?

At the moment my code looks like that:

```
struct membuf : std::streambuf
{
    membuf(char* begin, char* end) {
    this->setg(begin, begin, end);
    }
};

void read_stream(char* bufferIn, char* BufferOut, int lengthBufferIn)
{
    char* buffer = (char*) malloc(300);         //How do I do this globally??
    membuf sbuf(buffer, buffer + sizeof(buffer));//How do I do this globally??
    std::iostream s(&sbuf);             //How do I do this globally??

    s.write(bufferIn,  lengthBufferIn);
    s.read(BufferOut, 100);
    process(BufferOut);
}
```

Comment: For me it's not 100% clear what you are trying to achive, but it sounds like you should have a look at `std::queue` or `std::deque`

Answer (score 0):

I see no need for `iostream` here. You can create an object who has a reference to the buffer (so no copies involved) and to the position where it is left.

So something along this:

```
class Transformer {
private:
   char const *input_buf_;

public:
   Transformer(char const *buf) : input_buf_(buf) {
   }

   bool has_next() const { return input_buf_ != nullptr; } // or your own condition

   std::array<char, 300> read_next() {
       // read from input_buf_ as much as you need
       // advance input_buf_ to the remaining part
       // make sure to set input_buf_ accordingly after the last part
       // e.g. input_buf_ = nullptr; for how I wrote hasNext
       return /*the processed fixed size buffer*/;
   }
}
```

usage:

```
char *str == //...;
Transformer t(str);

while (t.has_next()) {
   std::array<char, 300> arr = t.read_next();
   // use arr
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Question 1: From my research it looks like iostream is the way to go, but apparently no one is using it. Is this the best way to go?

Yes (the std::istream class and specializations, are there to manage streams, and they fit the problem well).

Your code could look similar to this:

```
struct fixed_size_buffer
{
    static const std::size_t size = 300;
    std::vector<char> value;
    fixed_size_buffer() : value(fixed_size_buffer::size, ' ') {}
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, fixed_size_buffer& data)
{
    std::noskipws(in); // read spaces as well as characters
    std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<char>{ in },
         fixed_size_buffer::size);
         std::begin(data.value)); // this leaves in in an invalid state
                                  // if there is not enough data in the input
                                  // stream;
    return in;
}
```

Consuming the data:

```
fixed_size_buffer buffer;

std::ifstream fin{ "c:\\temp\\your_data.txt" };
while(fin >> buffer)
{
    // do something with buffer here
}

while(std::cin >> buffer) // read from standard input
{
    // do something with buffer here
}

std::istringstream sin{ "long-serialized-string-here" };
while(sin >> buffer) // read from standard input
{
    // do something with buffer here
}
```

> Question 2: How can I declare the iostream object globally? Actually, as I have several streams I will need to write the iostream Object in a struct-vector. How do I do this?

iostreams do not support copy-construction; Because of this, you will need to keep them in a sequence of pointers / references to base class:

```
auto fin = std::make_unique<std::ifstream>("path_to_input_file");
std::vector<std::istream*> streams;

streams.push_back(&std::cin);
streams.push_back(fin.get());

fixed_size_buffer buffer;
for(auto in_ptr: streams)
{
    std::istream& in = &in_ptr;
    while(in >> buffer)
    {
        // do something with buffer here
    }
}
```